# SR0004 - A column without an index that is used as IN predicate test expression might degrade performance

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm quite new to SQL so I have received the error as stated in my question title.

The attached image is my sql command.
[image]

If I do not use IN, 
I will get another error which is subquery returns more than 1 value...

How should I write it so that I would not get any of these error?

Below is the SQLcode:
BEGIN

```
   SELECT [c].[ChargeSubCategoryOID] ,[c].[Description], [c].[Qty], [c].[Uom], [c].[BeforeGovtSubsidy], [c].[AfterGovtSubsidy],

   [c].[ChargesIndicatorCode], [c].[ChargesIndicatorValue]

   FROM ChargeItems AS [c]

   WHERE

   [c].[ChargeSubCategoryOID] IN

   (

          SELECT [c].[OID]

          FROM ChargeSubCategories AS [c]

          WHERE

          [c].[ChargeCategoryOID] IN

          (

                 SELECT [cg].[OID]

                 FROM ChargeCategories AS [cg]

                 WHERE

                 [cg].[ChargeGroupOID] IN

                 (

                       SELECT [cg].[OID]

                       FROM ChargeGroups AS [cg]

                       WHERE

                       [cg].[InvoiceOID] IN

                       (

                              SELECT TOP(1)

                              [p].[OID]

                              FROM [Invoices] AS [p]

                              LEFT JOIN [Payors] AS [p.Payors] ON [p].[OID] = [p.Payors].[InvoiceOID]

                              LEFT JOIN [Details] AS [p.Details] ON [p].[OID] = [p.Details].[InvoiceOID]

                              WHERE ([p].[InvoiceReferenceNo] = @BillRefNo) AND ([p.Details].[IdentificationNoValue] = @Id)

                              ORDER BY [p].[CreationTime] DESC, [p].[OID], [p.Payors].[OID]       

                       )            

                 )     

   )

   )ORDER BY [c].[ChargeSubCategoryOID] ASC
```

END

Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: does this query fail to execute? it's looks like a performance suggestion. you can check the columns that you are using in `where` clause and add an index on them.

Comment: It executes successfully on MSSM. But on Visual studio database project's StoredProcedure it will have the errors as mentioned.

Comment: is it possible for you to edit your question and add tables and sample data in text and not use an image?

Comment: is p.Details.IdentificatinValue `unique` ? If so you can do without the last `IN ` statement

Comment: It looks to me that all those IN, to ensure that a value exists on another table, can simply be replaced by INNER JOINs

Comment: @Marc Guillot Yes, your understanding is right. Those IN, to ensure a value exists on another table. How could the above code be replaced using INNER JOINs? I'm having trouble doing that. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: @Fabian can you provide the SQL in text ?, it's far easier for us to just modify a text to replace the INs with INNER JOINs than having to retype everything.

Comment: @Marc Guillot I have just edited the post and provided the SQL in text. Thank you in advance for your help. Appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have replaced your INs with INNER JOINs. Notice that I have changed the aliases so they are all different, preventing ambiguity.

The only significant bit is the last JOIN, because I haven't inner joined the table Invoices but three left joined tables giving it an alias so you can set the join condition to the rest of your SQL statement.

```
SELECT it.ChargeSubCategoryOID ,it.Description, it.Qty, it.Uom, it.BeforeGovtSubsidy, 
       it.AfterGovtSubsidy, it.ChargesIndicatorCode, it.ChargesIndicatorValue
FROM ChargeItems AS it
     inner join ChargeSubcategories AS sc on sc.OID = it.ChargeSubCategoryOID
     inner join ChageCategories AS ct on ct.OID = sc.ChargeCategoryOID
     inner join ChargeGroups AS gr on gr.OID = ct.ChargeGroupOID
     inner join (select top 1 in.OID
                 from Invoices AS in
                      left join Payors AS py on py.InvoiceOID = in.OID
                      left join Details AS dt on dt.InvoiceOID = in.OID
                 where in.InvoiceReferenceNo = @BillRefNo AND dt.IdentificationNoValue = @Id
                 order by in.CreationTime desc, in.OID, py.OID
                ) AS in2 on in2.OID = gr.Invoice.OID
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Will definitely look up and familiarise myself with inner joins. Appreciate it!